# How to insert values into DataFrames from multiple dictionary objects in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've so many dictionary objects like

```
l= {'A':14,'B':45,'C':'ds'}
S= {'A':58,'B':78,'C':'rt'}  ..... so on
```

I want to take these values of multiple dictionaries into one **DataFrame** having same column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest is create list of `dict`s and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([l,S])
print (df)
    A   B   C
0  14  45  ds
1  58  78  rt
```